# when jtable open cell popup, then click the other cell,how to make the clicked cell request focus?

Tags: java, swing, popup, jtable, jcombobox

I have write java swing JTable, in the table, a cell like JComboBox, when I edit the JComboBox cell, it open the item list, then I clicked the other cell(JTextField),how to make the clicked cell request focus in the table? Now I need double click the JTextField cell, then it can grab the focus.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I got what you are facing.

Use method [ClickCountToStart](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#setClickCountToStart%28int%29) to enable editing in single click to the JTextfield which is inside the tablecell.
here is an example , about how you can use it

```
 DefaultCellEditor onSingleClick = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField());
    onSingleClick.setClickCountToStart(1);

    //set the editor to the every column
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        table.setDefaultEditor(table.getColumnClass(i),onSingleClick);
    }
```